# php How to read an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Struggling with this problem for an hour now and searched both stackoverflow and google and couldn't find an answer that helped. I have the following from `xdebug`:

```
 - list (array)

   -[0] (object)

     ---id  (string)

     ---proj_name  (string)

     ---proj_desc  (string)
```

I am trying to pull out the value of `id`. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$list[0]->id
```

- `$list` is an array containing an object at position `0`, therefore this object can be accessed with `$list[0]`
- the object has a property named `id`, which can be accessed with `$object->id`

If you have more than one object in the array, then you can loop through the values contained in the array with [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach). For example:

```
foreach ($list as $object) {
    echo $object->id . "<br/>";
}
```

This will take each object in the array and display its `id` value.

Comment: I had tried this, but the codeigniter program failed not recognizing the value when I called a controller from my form. Error elsewhere. Thanks for confirming and I am pointed in the right direction to solve now.

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach to loop through the list:

```
foreach($list as $obj)    // Where $list is the list containing the objects
{
   $id = $obj->id;
}
```