# How to read data from this array?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

It's pretty lame question but i still don't understand how to decipher how data inside arrays are structured

I'm using smarty and php.
Here's how my array looks like (printed from {debug}):

```
Array (2)
\r0 => stdClass Object (1)
\r  user => test
\r1 => stdClass Object (1)
\r  user => test2
```

How i can print these rows inside foreach?

I've tried this:

```
{foreach item=user_data from=$group_moderators}

{$user_data.user}

{/foreach}
```

or

```
{foreach item=user_data from=$group_moderators}

{$user_data@key.user}

{/foreach}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020849/php-how-to-read-an-array-of-objects

Comment: That's not gonna work in smarty.

Answer (score 1):

```
{foreach from=$group_moderators item=user_data}
```

In this foreach you might use :

```
{$user_data|@print_r}
```

So you can see what's in this var.

To access properties use `->` eg :

```
{$user_data->user_login}
```

Comment: Well, there's an object inside it: stdClass Object ( [user_login] => test ) 1 stdClass Object ( [user_login] => test2 ) 1  how i can access it? {$user_data@key.user_login} doesn't work.